# netbeans sapui5 code-completion for xmlViews

Tags: xml, netbeans, sapui5, code-completion

I'm trying to get the code completion to work for XMLViews in Netbeans for some days. But unfortunately I could not figure out how to get the XML code completion to work for SAPUI5 XMLViews.

I found 3 interesting posting to that topic.

1) https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/7
That post describes were to get the needed JS and XSD files for code completion.
Unzipping the JAR files and coping the resource folder from META-INF folder into my project gave me a great autocompletion for the JS files.

2) https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/22/configuring-jetbrains-webstorm-for-ui5-development/
Describes XML validation and code completion when using XML Views for WebStorm IDE.

3) http://ewaldertl.blogspot.de/2013/11/code-completion-in-xml-documents-within.html
Describes Code Completion in XML Documents within NetBeans 7.4 and a XSD.

Have anybody some experience with that topic or could give me a hint what I could try to get it work.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you find a way for Code Completion?

Comment: No, I don't found a way. Maybe There is now a possiblity but I didn't look for it anymore. If someone would find one I would be still interested.

Comment: Even point 1 does not work, for JS files?